# Office Interop Outlook Adding a new button to edit e-mail body

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop

I am trying to create an outlook addin which is all about to add a button to New Mail window. When the button is clicked I must add a specific text to mail body. What is the best way to do this?

I also tried adding a button in a custom ribbon. But I couldn't get the active inspector so that I could have the MailItem object. Is there anyway to accomplish this? Any ideas are welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()` will give you the active inspector. What was the error message when you tried this?

You will need a reference to the `MailItem`, so you need the inspector once the button in the Ribbon is clicked. Once you have the `MailItem` you can access the text body or html body depending on the `Outlook.MailItem.BodyFormat` flag. `Outlook.MailItem.Body` will give you the text body, while `Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody` will provide you access to the HTML body for appending your custom text.

You could also use a context menu, custom task pane, custom form region, etc. Your best bet is to stick with the Ribbon UI since the users already understand the interaction. You can also control placement of your button in the Ribbon (*which tab, sort order, etc.*).

Comment: thank you so much, I eventually managed to get the MailItem. I can do it with button in the ribbon, my next challenge is to place the button on new mail screen, so user will be able to click only once, again ty so much.